# Write a function that accepts either a 1D or a 2D array as input - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, types, arguments, overloading

I am trying to write a function that accepts two different types as an argument. This example is a matrix multiplication function, and I would like it to work for 1D or 2D arrays so that I could use it to multiply two matrices or to multiply a matrix and a vector. Is this possible?

```
Private Function MatrixMultiplication(byVal input1 As Type1, byVal input2 as Type2)
    If Type1 == Double(,) And Type2 == Double(,) Then
        Do Something
    ElIf Type1 == Double(,) And Type2 == Double() Then
        Do Something
End Function
```

Edit: Someone suggested this question is a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659529/duplicate-code-and-method-overloading-overriding). I declined that question as an answer to mine because the scope is different. That question is about unnecessarily duplicating code when overriding. This question is about passing passing parameters of different type, specifically 1D arrays and 2D arrays, to the same function. Overloading was a solution to this problem, but the questions were completely different. Since I couldn't find the answer I was looking for without knowing the word "overload," I believe it is important for others to find this answer if they run into the same question.

Comment: You can overload that method. One version as `(input1 As Double(,), input2 As Double())` and one as `(input1 As Double(,), input2 As Double(,))` (`ByVal` is the default). -- Your Functions should have a return value.

Comment: Oh, so you just write the function twice with the same name and VB will automatically use the version in which the parameters match?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could also use class wrappers that contain the methods and operators used to process the arrays and cast to defined Types, possibly using a common Interface that defines the methods to call when the generic arguments are processed. So the functions would look like, e.g. `Private Function MatrixMultiplication(Of T, U As {IInterfaceType1, IInterfaceType2})(input1 As T, input2 As U) As T` or `Private Function MatrixMultiplication(Of T As {IInterfaceType(Of Double(,))})(input1 As T, input2 As T) As T` etc.

Comment: [Overloaded properties and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/overloaded-properties-and-methods)  -- [Generic Types in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types) -- [How to: Define an Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-define-an-operator)

Comment: Man, that just went way over my head. I guess I need to read about how to use interfaces. This seems very useful, but new to me. For now overloading will work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to write an answer yourself and accept it when you have resolved the issue (assuming permissions allow) so that we can all see that you don't need any more help without opening the question and reading all the comments. Jimi won't write an answer because he doesn't care if the rest of us waste our time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out no matter how much I searched, I couldn't find the answer because I didn't know the word "overload." Thank you Jimi for providing the answer in the comments. I overloaded the function and it works! Here's my code, in case anyone's wondering. Thanks again.

```
    Private Function matrixMultiply(A As Double(,), B As Double(,)) As Double(,)
        If A.GetUpperBound(1) = B.GetUpperBound(0) Then
            ' A(m x n) * B(n x o) = C(m x o)
            Dim C(A.GetUpperBound(0), B.GetUpperBound(1)) As Double
            ' C(i,j) = Sum(k=1 to n)(A(i,k)*B(k,j))
            For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                For j As Integer = 0 To B.GetUpperBound(1)
                    For k As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                        C(i, j) += A(i, k) * B(k, j)
                    Next
                Next
            Next
            Return C
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Array dimensions do not match for multiplication"))
        End If
    End Function

    ' overloaded
    Private Function matrixMultiply(A As Double(,), B As Double()) As Double()
        If A.GetUpperBound(1) = B.GetUpperBound(0) Then
            Dim C(A.GetUpperBound(0)) As Double
            For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                For j = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                    C(i) += A(i, j) * B(j)
                Next
            Next
            Return C
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Array dimensions do not match for multiplication"))
        End If
```